# Создать синоним метки [localization] на метку [локализация]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [localization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization), и так как у нас предпочтительнее русские названия меток, предлагаю создать ей синоним [локализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: Там всего 6 использований, вычистил. Ещё есть метка [tag:locale], надо бы про неё тоже принять решение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Насколько я понимаю, простой чистки недостаточно, потому что это не предотвращает создания новых вопросов с англоязычной меткой. Именно поэтому я и попросил создание синонима.

Comment: так одно другому не помешает )

Comment: @NickVolynkin а метку locale, думаю, стоит просто переименовать в локаль.

Comment: что-то странное сейчас было. Нашел вопрос по метке locale, но в момент правки метка исчезла, и даже в истории её нет. Прямо перед нажатием на кнопку «редактировать метки» метка была. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/125225/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, locale («локаль») — хотя и связана с локализацией, но является вполне самостоятельным техническим понятием.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да, я согласен. Я исправлял locale на локаль.

Answer (score 2):

Создам отдельный ответ для возможности голосования:

[localization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) -> [локализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

[internationalization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) -> [интернационализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score -4):

предлагаю воспользоваться [общепринятыми](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) сокращениями для терминов:

localization → l10n

internationalization → i18n

Comment: Мне нравится, но все ли поймут?

Comment: те, кто «в теме» — прекрасно поймут. для тех, кто «не в теме», есть краткое и подробное описание метки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, допускаю, что у меня произошла некоторая «профдеформация» от тесного соприкосновения с l10n и i18n всевозможных пакетов свободного п.о., в результате которой написанные целиком слова l10n и i18n выглядят в некотором смысле «дико» и требуют несколько большего времени на осознание своего смысла, чем сокращённые варианты.

Comment: хех, я тоже i18n воспринимаю быстрее, чем полное слово. Но можно представить испуг новичка, у которого какой-нибудь «перевод» заменяется на непонятный [13375p34k](https://www.google.ru/?hl=xx-hacker&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=7d7mVfyJIuXmywPplpzwAg)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это ж совсем «из другой оперы».

Comment: Не уверен, что метка [локализация] хуже метки [l10n]. Это мало того, что сокращение, так ещё и англоязычное.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, в «узких кругах» тех, кто «воюет» с проблемами локализации и интернационализации, термины *l10n* и *i18n*, мне кажется, будут более приемлемы и понятны. но, ещё раз повторюсь, на мое мнение, скорее всего влияет эта самая «профдеформация».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, они мне знакомы. Но я против из-за того, что у нас русскоязычный сайт и что есть русскоязычные термины для этих понятий